# AVAudioSessionCategoryAudioProcessing: is the lack of interruption notifications guaranteed?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudiosession

If I set my `AVAudioSession`'s category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryAudioProcessing`, I do not receive any interruption notifications regardless of what else I'm doing. (Locking the device, playing audio in another app, etc.) I understand why this is — `AVAudioSessionCategoryAudioProcessing` is for offline rendering with no input or output — but can this behavior be relied upon? Is it documented anywhere? Are there any situations in which a processing session will receive interruption notifications?

Answer (score 2):

Like you say, `AVAudioSessionCategoryAudioProcessing` not causing interruptions sort of makes sense, but on the other hand, offline audio rendering/decoding/encoding/transcoding can use hardware codecs (that's a good thing), and audio interruptions once indicated that the hardware was no longer available and by the way your codec state had been trashed, hope you enjoy guessing which parts of your decompressed audio contains bald spots.

So in a sane world, either `AVAudioSessionCategoryAudioProcessing` causes all your codecs to be of the software no-need-to-know-about-interruptions variety, or something clever is happening under the hood to ensure that your use of hardware codecs does not cause any discontinuities should the hardware be taken away from you.

In answer to your question, I can't find any documentation on the behaviour. You could try to listen for interruptions, and route changes then try airplay, launching the music app, plugging in audio cards, ripping out the headphones, playing over hdmi, receiving phone calls, alarms, playing back a movie and so on to see if you get any interruptions.

But can the behaviour be relied up on? I would say no, because it looks like [`AVAudioSessionCategoryAudioProcessing` has been deprecated in iOS10](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryaudioprocessing). I have no idea why, nor can I find any reference to it on [asciiwwdc](http://asciiwwdc.com).